# How to run virtual machines on a chromebook

Tags: virtual-machine, chrome-os

I have a **Acer R11 (X86)** chrome-book that has a kernel issue with running virtual box and vmware player (Yes I installed kernel headers, they are incompatible with my kernel and virtual box).

If there is a android app for virtualisation I should be able to install it. If there is a native virtualisation app for chrome os please show me. I do not care if I have to do heavy modifications of system files. 
I am in developer mode.

Comment: I'm leaving a negative vote here, your question is sill not clear about what kind of virtualization you want and you are criticizing me for not giving you the answer you expect while not providing the full details that would enable me to give that answer.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of kernel headers did you install and what operating system are you running?

I wasn't aware that you can install kernel headers for Chrome OS itself. If you run a chroot in Chrome OS (e.g. crouton) and have installed kernel headers in the chroot then this won't work out as expected since you are not running the kernel from the chroot.

Here is the section from the [crouton README.md](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton) that you indeed should have read:

> ## What's a chroot?
>
> Like virtualization, chroots provide the guest OS with their own,
>   segregated file system to run in, allowing applications to run in a
>   different binary environment from the host OS. **Unlike virtualization,
>   you are not booting a second OS**; instead, the guest OS is running
>   using the Chromium OS system. …

I don't know if it's Chrome OS that doesn't allow you to run VMs on your particular hardware/firmware combination. I had no problems running a Windows 10 Insider VM with VirtualBox on my ASUS Flip C302 [with GalliumOS](https://chrx.org/) and I just installed VirtualBox in GalliumOS on my little N22 to run [Redox OS](https://www.redox-os.org/) and make this photo as proof that you can run virtual machines on Chromebooks, but not in Chrome OS (edit until ChromeOS itself ships a feature that does this out of the box being it Linux containers or actual virtual machines):

[image]

Comment: After doing some more research that are incompatible kernel from chrome os that is in turn making the kernel of the chroot based on the chrome os kernel and sense than is a 3.18 kernel before virtualization was wide spread there is hit and miss support for it

Comment: No I think you are on the wrong track. You have to boot a non-Chrome OS Linux distribution and kernel, then you will be able to run virtual machines. [chroot uses your current kernel](https://askubuntu.com/a/464849/40581), not the one in chroot. It's nice that you can do so many things with chroot on Chromebooks, but it has its limitations and this is one if it.

Comment: Do you even know what crouton is also my chromebook is on the verified list

Comment: Verified list of what? Complete sentences with all the information one needs to give a good answer to your question please. [ARC++](https://lwn.net/Articles/701964/) aka Android apps on chrome won't bring you virtualization since there don't [appear to be any apps for this](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/84359/20651) nor will [containers](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/issues/364#issuecomment-263691719) bring you full virtualization as one expects from VirtualBox/VMware. Please ask a precise question next time, I'm going to spend my time on other questions now.